# React DnD make dropTargets when hover on something while dragging item

Tags: reactjs, react-dnd

I'm trying to do something like below:

[image]

Scenario 1: User will drag and drop List 1 from left side to right side.

Scenario 2: Again, User will drag list 2 to right side, when that dragging item hover on list 1, have to show drop zones to drop that list 2 item here.

Finally, List 1 and List 2 both will be placed like left and right side.

With React Dnd, Is this achievable?  and I tried this it works only while dragging.  https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-pctpdh

I'm able to show a drop area while dragging, it shows every time, but I need to show that drop area only hover on some item.

Below is the sample work, I have to achieve:

[image]

Need to show placeholder to drop an item while hover other items to drop. (Need to Create dynamic drop targets while mouse hover some item)

I need a help on this to achieve this feature.Any idea on this really commendable.

Answer (score 1):

I saw the code snippet and i added some new code that replicates your desired behavior.

The idea is to create a separate component to handle drop actions, that can be reused when is needed. In this particular case, I choose to use the component inside your `ListItem` component to create two drop zones on both sides.

Here is the updated code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-pctpdh

Comment: Thank you so much and sorry I couldn't see the hover behavior on the stackblitz. Expected behavior is when a new list item is dragging over on already dragged item, I need to show drop area to drop new item.
I have to create new drop area only when mouse over an item already dropped,Hope you're getting it again thanks for stepping by. Guess, You didn't fork

Comment: I tried like show placeholders while hover(item, monitor, component) { } , but it seems like not working.

Comment: That's simple, you can conditionally render drop areas based on `isOverCurrent` value. If it's `true` show them, otherwise hide them. You don't need to use `hover` callback to achieve the desired behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I am able to do it but I'd like to know is this a correct way to do this, you can check it here https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-pctpdh and there's junky animation happening whenever hover list 1

Comment: Hi, did you find the solution ? Can you please share it with me if you had the solution. I am stack for 5 days and can't find a soultion.